# how to store data in model which contain foreign key in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

**models.py**

```
class event_details(models.Model):
    e_id = models.AutoField(primary_key= True)
```

```
class participants(models.Model):
    p_id = models.AutoField(primary_key= True)
    p_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.p_id)
```

```
class event(models.Model):
    e_id = models.ForeignKey(event_details,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'event_id')
    p_id = models.ForeignKey(participants, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'pp_id')
```

**view.py**

```
def add_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name =request.POST.get('name') 
      
        reg = participants(
            e_id = 1,
            p_name = name,
        )
        reg.save()
        
    return render(request,'web/Registration.html')
```

Try to Store Participate name But Error that "participants.e_id" must be a "event_details" instance.
can help me to solve it by store data in participants model

Comment: You called 'p_id' to the id of the participants model, not 'e_id '.

Comment: p_id will be generated automatically, I want to connect that p_id with e_id which is already there.